# How to make form elements inline?

Tags: html, css, forms, input, label

I'm new to all this, so any help is appreciated.

I have this form I'm trying to style, but can't seem to figure out what the problem is. I need the CTA button to be next to the input field, without changing the html. What am I missing in my css?

HTML:

```
<div id="newsletter" class="form-wrap">
    <p class="form-field">
        <label for="newsletter_email">Please enter your email</label>
        <input type="text" name="newsletter_email" id="newsletter_email" value="" placeholder="Enter email address"/>
    </p>

    <p class="form-submit">
        <input type="submit" name="newsletter_submit" id="newsletter_submit" value="Get Early Access"/>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: "*just pull up page source and css files in your browser*" — no: you reduce the code to the [minimum necessary amount to demonstrate the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and add it to your question. Otherwise as soon as you update your site with the solution this question ceases to be of any use to anyone else.

Comment: Thanks for the insight David. Sorry about that.

Comment: just added .form-wrap {position:relative;} to css and it worked!

Comment: It is also very useful to us if you post a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Thanks @BunnyMan. Sorry, I'm new to all this so thanks for the additional insight. I'll remember that next time.

Comment: That's fine. We all started sometime, I started SO just a couple months ago.

Comment: Would you consider answering your own question to formally close it? Of course, you should heed David's suggestions before you do so.

Comment: Yes, let me answer my own question with David's suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't let me answer my own question until later, so I just edited my original question...I also answered it with the 3rd comment above.